# How to group user sessions by converted row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm doing simple multichannel attribution exploration and got stuck with grouping user sessions.

For example, I have simple sessions table:

```
client channel time converted
1   social  1   0
1   cpc     2   0
1   email   3   1
1   email   4   0
1   cpc     5   1
2   organic 1   0
2   cpc     2   1
3   email   1   0
```

Each row contains user sessions and *converted* column, which shows if user converted in particular session.

I need to group sessions which lead conversion for each user and for each conversion, so perfect result should be:

```
client channels time converted
1 [social,cpc,email] 3  1
1 [email,cpc]        5  1
2 [organic,cpc]      2  1
3 [email]            1  0
```

Notice user 3, he's not converted but I need to have his sessions

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a group.  For this purpose, an inverse sum of `converted` looks like the right thing:

```
select client, array_agg(channel order by time) as channels,
       max(time) as time, max(converted) as converted
from (select t.*,
             sum(t.converted) over (partition by t.client order by t.time desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by client, grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  client, 
  STRING_AGG(channel ORDER BY time) channels,
  MAX(time) time,
  MAX(converted) converted 
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(converted = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY client ORDER BY time DESC) session
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
)
GROUP BY client, session 
-- ORDER BY client, time
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 client, 'social' channel, 1 time, 0 converted UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'cpc', 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'email', 3, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'email', 4, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'cpc', 5, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'organic', 1, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'cpc', 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'email', 1, 0 
)
SELECT 
  client, 
  STRING_AGG(channel ORDER BY time) channels,
  MAX(time) time,
  MAX(converted) converted 
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(converted = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY client ORDER BY time DESC) session
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
)
GROUP BY client, session 
ORDER BY client, time
```

with result

```
Row client  channels            time    converted    
1   1       social,cpc,email    3       1    
2   1       email,cpc           5       1    
3   2       organic,cpc         2       1    
4   3       email               1       0
```